# INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE from SalesForce iOS SDK

Tags: ios, salesforce

I am using salesforce iOS sdk in my project. I am creating a record in my local db and update another record . Now i am trying to sync up my records to salesforce server. I am getting error.

> "soupName" : "Attachment" } cause:Server call for sync up failed
>   errorError
>   Domain=https://ev.cs16.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Attachment/00Pf00000030kVhEAI Code=400
>   "(null)" UserInfo={error=(         {         errorCode =
>   "INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE";         fields =         (        
>       ParentId         );         message = "Unable to create/update fields: ParentId. Please check the security settings of this field and
>   verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.";  
>     } )}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the underlying Salesforce error (extracted from your question) is:

`Unable to create/update fields: ParentId. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.`

Basically this just means that the user you are performing the insert operation with has no permissions to set the ParentId.

If you are trying to change the ParentId in a Master-Detail relationship, make sure that the `Allow reparenting` option is activated in the Master-Detail settings.